# Why some records are not retrieved ( EF6-Add-Migration with DbContext)

Tags: database, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

Created an API that retrieves data from SQL Server. I'm using an `OnModelCreating()` method to establish table relationship. Both parent has PK `mykey`, the child tables have a foreign key `mykey`.

The parent class includes the `list<>` of the children in the class;

```
public List(Child1)? Child1 { get; set; }
public List(Child2)? Child2 { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // override for Child1 Table      
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasMany(o => o.Child1)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.mykey)
                .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.mykey); 

    // override for Child2 Table
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Child2)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.mykey)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.mykey);   
}
```

The JSON output is incomplete.

The Parent and Child1 arrays are populated but **Child2** in some instance is empty

`Child2[]` even though the data and relation is there

```
 "mykey": 6,
 "lastName": "WINGERTER",
 "creationDate": "2023-08-03T20:40:49.547",
 "Child1": [
     {
         "sSer": 12,
         "mykey": 6,
         "Name": "lateral",
         "creationDate": "2023-04-27T15:34:15.19",
     }
 ],
 "Child2": [] ----->Why is it empty-it contains a mykey=6?
```

What is confusing is that it retrieves data for other `mykey` values.